# Получение данных с интернета и обновление ячейки excelя

Tags: веб-программирование, excel

Есть такой сайт xe.com, там значит обмен валют по текущему курсу идет, и обновляется курс каждую минуту. Я создал не большую таблицу в экселе расчет рублей в евра по курсу конкретному, но т.к. курс меняется, то мне надо чтобы эксель брал обновленный курс с сайта, и помещял этот курс, к примеру в ячейку S1. Как только я запустил эксель курс тут же обновился и все данные, где используется эта цифра(сколько 1 рубль в евра) автоматические обновлялись...как-то так..

Comment: Осторожнее только - насколько я помню вы таким образом нарушаете [лицензию на использование данных из xe.com](http://www.xe.com/legal/) - я в свое время уже нарывался на грубость их юристов :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать такую функцию - она заполняет первую ячейку курсом:

```vb
Sub getRurEurRate()

Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
Dim cell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell

'get page content
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With xhr

    .Open "GET", "http://www.xe.com/?c=RUB", False
    .send

    If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    Else
        MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & _
        vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
    End If

End With

'get rate from table
Set table = doc.getElementById("xRatesBxTable")
Set row = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(8)
Set cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2)

' Put to excel cell
Cells(1, 1).Value = cell.innerText

End Sub
```

Это рабочий код, но довольно топорный. Курс берется из конкретной ячейки и если, допустим, добавится еще одна строка в таблицу перед нужной - он будет работать не корректно. Так что это вам просто реализация, от которой можно отталкиваться.

И нужно в редакторе vba включить `Tools - References`:

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft XML, v6.0

Answer (score 0):

На `PHP` это делается с помощью библиотеки [PHPExcel](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel) (которая позволяет читать и записывать любые данные в exel). В случае с обновлением данных в Excell. На `Go` (golang) это делается с помощью [этой](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx) библиотеки.
Также есть похожие библиотеки и на других языках программирования ([python](http://www.python-excel.org/), [Ruby](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL)), но я рекомендую обратить внимание на PHPExcel т.к. она проверена временем и может работать с `xls` 2003 и `xlsx` 2007+. Точно не скажу по поводу обновления ячейки, но файл целиком обновить получится без проблем. Но если говорить про `web`, то допустим на "сайте" будет ссылка на файл, кликая на который вы получаете каждый раз файл с обновленными данными. Обновление файла происходит по планировщику `cron` к примеру. Или при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Прочитал все, и, ничего не понял:-(
А почему именно php ? Excel 2016

Comment: @Ratevaio да, собственно, при должном знании VBA, можно и на нем написать, в самом Excel

Comment: С помощью того что я расписал выше можно получать свежие данные каждую минуту (час, день...). Просто вы упомянули `web` а `php` это как бы то что смотрит как раз в эту сторону (на других `web` технологиях это вряд ли получится). Если вы планируете поместить десятки тысяч строк в `xls` файл, то `PHPExcel` библиотека с этим справится (проверено мною лично). Если же нужно вытащить одну строчку, то можно и `VBA`.

Answer (score 0):

Без программирования.

*Excel* имеет встроенный инструмент для подключения внешних данных.

Меню *Данные*, блок **Получение_внешных_данных**-*из_Интернета*. Открывается окно поисковика. В строку поиска ввести адрес нужного сайта, нажать *Enter*.

После загрузки страницы на таблицах, которые можно импортировать в *Excel*, видны стрелки на желтом фоне. При  клике на стрелке она превращается в галку, фон становится зеленым. Это значит, что таблица выбрана для импорта в *Excel*.
Клик на галке возвращает стрелку в исходное состояние.

После выбора таблиц нажать кнопку *Импорт* (в  правом нижнем углу). В появившемся окне *Импорт данных* следует указать ячейку размещения импортированных данных. Здесь же можно настроить свойства диапазона. *ОК* - подключение произведено, данные вставлены на лист.

Свойства диапазона можно настроить и после импорта - кликнуть ПКМ на любой из ячеек выгрузки.

Данные обновляются при открытии книги или при выборе из меню (ПКМ на любой из ячеек выгрузки).

Больше информации можно получить, спросив у любого поисковика:

**Excel Получение внешних данных из Интернета**